# partition set {1,2,...,9} into subsets of size 2 and 5?

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I do some ex for preparing discrete mathematics exam, i get stuck in one problem, anyone could help me?

> How many ways we can partition set {1,2,...,9} into subsets of size 2
>   and 5?

anyway, some tutorials for solving such a question...

Edit: Like always Scott is Right...

Comment: There is a question on what you are actually asking. Are you asking how many ways there are to pick subsets of size $5$ and size $2$ from a set of $9$ (pick a board of directors of $5$ people with $2$ alternates from a pool of $9$ people); or are you asking how many ways there are to partition a set of $9$ into subsets of size $5$, $2$, and $2$?

Comment: @robjohn,  how many ways there are to partition a set of 9 into subsets of size 5, and 2 ?

Comment: That is restating your question. Is it the first interpretation or the second?

Comment: @robjohn See a definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set

Comment: @robjohn: The term partition of a set is completely unambiguous. Besides you use it yourself in the second alternative. So clearly that one is the intended one. Equivalent question: how many equivalence relations exist on a given set of $9$ elements such that each equivalence class either has size $5$ or size $2$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: yes, I was trying to determine if the word "partition" was being used properly, or whether the OP simply meant "pick". However, now that the "s" has been added, I assume that it is.

Comment: it's select precisely @robjohn.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A partition of $\{1,\ldots,9\}$ into sets of sizes $2$ and $5$ must contain two sets of size $2$ and one of size $5$: no other combination of $2$’s and $5$’s adds up to $9$. Thus, the question boils down to determining how many ways there are to pick a $5$-element subset of $\{1,\ldots,9\}$ and then split the remaining $4$ elements into two $2$-element subsets.

The first part of that is easy: a $9$-element set has $\binom95$ $5$-element subsets, so there are $\binom95=126$ ways to choose the $5$-element piece of our partition. The second step step is just a little trickier. You might be tempted to think that there are $\binom42=6$ ways to choose $2$ of the remaining $4$ elements for one of the $2$-element sets, leaving the other $2$ to be the other $2$-element set, but that’s not quite right. Suppose that your $5$-element set is $\{1,3,5,7,9\}$, so you’re making up two $2$-element sets from $\{2,4,6,8\}$. You might pick $\{2,6\}$ for one of your $2$-element sets, leaving $\{4,8\}$ for the other. Unfortunately, you might equally well pick $\{4,8\}$, leaving $\{2,6\}$ for the other. That figure of $\binom42$ counts these two choices separately, even though they produce the same two $2$-element sets.

You can avoid this in at least two ways. One is to notice that each pair of $2$-element sets is being counted twice, once for each of the two sets, so that instead of getting $\binom42$ pairs of $2$-element sets, we’re getting only half that many, i.e., $3$. The other is to employ a trick that’s useful quite often. No matter what $4$ elements remain after you’ve picked the $5$-element set, you can list them in numerical order; call them $n_1<n_2<n_3<n_4$. When we split them into two pairs, we have to pair one of the numbers $n_2,n_3$, and $n_4$ with the smallest one, $n_1$; obviously we can do that in $3$ ways. And once we’ve done that, there’s no more choosing to be done: the two numbers that we didn’t pair with $n_1$ form the last $2$-element set.

One way or another, we reach the final result: there are

$$\binom95\cdot3=126\cdot3=378$$

such partitions.

Comment: However, if the remaining four numbers, after choosing the five, are $\{1,2,3,4\}$ there *are* $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to choose the two for the set of two. The set of two picked and the two remaining are distinct.

Comment: @robjohn: No, that’s incorrect. There are *two* sets of $2$ involved, since we’re talking about a partition of $[9]$. There are *not* $\binom42$ ways to split $\{1,2,3,4\}$ into the two $2$-element members of the partition.

Comment: Since only a set of size $5$ and a set of size $2$ are mentioned, I considered "partition" to not mean partition in that sense. I interpret the question to be how many ways to pick a set of size $5$ and a set of size $2$ from a set of size $9$. If the question is how to partition a set of $9$ in to sets of size $5$, $2$, and $2$, then you are correct.

Comment: @robjohn: I thought it more likely that an *s* was lost from *subsets* than that the relatively unfamiliar technical term *partition* was used by accident, so to speak. (And if I’m wrong, I did at least make clear at the very beginning of the answer what I was actually counting!)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, like always you are right.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott You might express it this way: for any partitioning of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ *one* of subsets contains item $1$ and there are exactly $3$ items to choose a pair for the $1$. Then the remaining two items go into the other subset with no further choices, so there are exactly $3$ ways to partition 4-items set into two 2-item sets.

Comment: @CiaPan: That's essentially what I did, except that I used a general $4$-element set instead of a specific one.

Answer (score 4):

Since there are an odd number of elements in the set you must have a subset with 5 elements and therefore you must have two subsets of 2 elements.

First Choose the set with five elements. There are $9 \choose 5$ ways to do this. For *each* of these choices there are then 4 elements left and you have to pick two. Finally the last subset is determined by your choices of the first two. So the total number of ways should be.

$$
{9 \choose 5} {4 \choose 2}
$$

...

Might as well leave my mistake in as it helps make a good point at the expense of only slight embarrassment. The final answer is of course half this amount. Thanks to Brian for pointing this out. I am choosing two numbers from 4 but I'm putting 2 numbers in set A and 2 numbers in set B. However A, B is the same partition as B,A.

Comment: This is too big by a factor of $2$; see my answer.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thanks for that.

Comment: I think the question may be unclear (or missing an *s* in *subset*).  This is the correct answer for selecting a subset of size $2$ and a subset of size $5$ which do not overlap, but twice as many as the number of ways of completely partitioning into (two) subsets of size $2$ and (one) of size $5$.

Comment: Indeed - I'm a little embarrassed that 3 people have voted my answer up when it contains an error and only 2 have voted for Brian's correct answer.

Comment: I was thinking of deleting but I think it's actually useful to the OP to show that its easy to make a mistake in combinatorics. A partition is a set of subsets so order does not matter either within the subsets *or* between the subsets

Comment: @MichaelE: I am not sure what the OP intended. Depending on whether they used partition in the sense of dividing a set if $9$ in to subsets of size $5$, $2$, and $2$, then Brian is correct. However, if they meant how many ways are there to pick subsets of size $5$ and size $2$ from a set of size $9$, then your answer is correct.

Comment: Yes you are right - the (s) in the question does change the answer but in my answer I said that the last subset is determined by the choice of the other 2. I must have been thinking subsets (plural) then so I think my next statement has to go down as a misstep. What might have been a typo in has turned this into a much more interesting question.